# Unable to get flutter packages

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am behind a proxy & have set the http and https proxy env variables correctly, but I get 403 errors when I try and run

```
$ flutter packages get -v
```

The process hangs for a while, then errors trying to access https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
How can I trouble shoot this?

Full output is

```
rossco-mac:flutter_apptst rossco$ flutter packages get -v
[ +119 ms] executing: [/Users/rossco/dev/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +42 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] bbfbf1770cca2da7c82e887e4e4af910034800b6
[        ] executing: [/Users/rossco/dev/flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[ +242 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[        ] 1.20.2
[  +10 ms] executing: [/Users/rossco/dev/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/Users/rossco/dev/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] git://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +54 ms] executing: [/Users/rossco/dev/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +12 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +34 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[   +9 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +98 ms] Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_apptst...
[   +3 ms] Using /Users/rossco/dev/flutter/.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/rossco/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_apptst/] /Users/rossco/dev/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/pub --trace --verbose get
--no-precompile
[  +66 ms] FINE: Pub 2.9.1
[  +51 ms] MSG : Resolving dependencies...
[  +13 ms] SLVR: fact: flutter_apptst is 1.0.0+1
[   +5 ms] SLVR: derived: flutter_apptst
[  +26 ms] SLVR: fact: flutter_apptst depends on flutter any from sdk
[        ] SLVR: fact: flutter_apptst depends on cupertino_icons ^0.1.3
[        ] SLVR: fact: flutter_apptst depends on flutter_test any from sdk
[   +1 ms] SLVR:   selecting flutter_apptst
[        ] SLVR:   derived: flutter_test any from sdk
[        ] SLVR:   derived: cupertino_icons ^0.1.3
[        ] SLVR:   derived: flutter any from sdk
[  +28 ms] IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons.
[  +20 ms] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
[        ]     | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
[        ]     | X-Pub-OS: macos
[        ]     | X-Pub-Command: get
[        ]     | X-Pub-Session-ID: 95202F77-60D4-420E-8F6F-D563B62C9CB2
[        ]     | X-Pub-Environment: flutter_bot:flutter_cli:get
[        ]     | X-Pub-Reason: direct
[        ]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.9.1
```

Hangs for a while then retries

Comment: "have set the http and https proxy env variables correctly" How?

Comment: in my ~/.basrc I have export https_proxy=https://myproxy.com.au:10091 and the same for http_proxy, it is just traffic over HTTPS getting these errors, but everything from my browser works fine

Comment: if this was as Java error I would look at the cacerts trust store, but I'm new to Flutter and dart & not sure where to start even troubleshooting this